# Android Gradle build tools DOC

Tags: android, gradle

The problem is: I want to learmore about android gradle build system. Is the build system is open source OR is there a full document showing all the members of the system(such as there are memebers    buildToolsVersion ,lintOptions and  many others I don't know).
After some doing some google,I just find some page while donnot have detail doc!!
I got page [how to config](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-build.html#configBuild) 
Any detail info is needed!
THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugin documentation is here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide

Source code can be obtained here: http://tools.android.com/build/gradleplugin

Comment: In My country(China) i cannot open these pages,While I goto the pages through VPN. I GOT the ANSWER!! THANKS!!